# .net mvc3 get roles of user

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am trying to get a list of roles for a particular user (not the current one logged in).

I figured out how to do this:

```
var theUser = Membership.GetUser(username)
```

But that just returns a MembershipUser object, which doesn't seem to have a isInRole method.

Is if I have the username as a string, how do I get a list of roles, or check that the user is in a particular role?

I am using all of the default authentication and membership providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(username, role);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser("username");
```